# Show/hide div input radio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to show/hide a div when a specific value is selected but I think the JavaScript selector 'or' doesn't not working. But its working when there is only one condition. I checked the documentation but nothing helped me

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: auto !important;">
            <tbody class="table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <td rowspan="4" style="vertical-align: middle;">Le salarié a-t-il un projet professionnel ?</td>
                    <td>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="choixPP" id="choixPP" value="LE"> à Limousin Expansion
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="choixPP" id="choixPP" value="CRL"> au Conseil Régional du Limousin
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="choixPP" id="choixPP" value="EXT"> a l'extérieur
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                            <input type="radio" name="choixPP" id="choixPP" value="0" checked> pas de projet professionnel
                        </label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" id="divChoixPP" style="display:none;">
        <label for="divChoixPP" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Si oui, préciser le projet</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="divChoixPP" id="divChoixPP" rows="6" cols="20"></textarea>
        </div>
        <!-- .col-sm-6 -->
    </div>
    <!-- .form-group -->
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#divChoixPP").hide();

    $("input:radio[name='choixPP']").change(function () {

        if (this.value == 'LE' || 'CRL' || 'EXT' && this.checked) {
            $("#divChoixPP").show();
        } else {
            $("#divChoixPP").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You're using the 'OR' operator wrong. It should be something like this.value == 'LE' || this.value == 'CRL' ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if(this.value == 'LE' || 'CRL' || 'EXT')
```

is not doing what you think it is doing. This is just checking the value equals to `LE`. The OR operator is **short-circuit** to get the first truthy value. As any non-empty string is truthy, `this.value == 'LE' || 'CRL' || 'EXT'` expression is evaluated to `this.value == 'LE'`

Use

```
if(this.value === 'LE' || this.value === 'CRL' || this.value ==='EXT'
```

Or create an array and check if the element is present in the array.

```
var values = ['LE', 'CRL', 'EXT'];

if (values.indexOf(this.value) !== -1)
```

---

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var values = ['LE', 'CRL', 'EXT'];

  $("input:radio[name='choixPP']").change(function() {
    $('#divChoixPP').toggle(this.checked && values.indexOf(this.value) !== -1)
  });
});
```

```css
#divChoixPP {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered" style="width: auto !important;">
      <tbody class="table-striped">
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="4" style="vertical-align: middle;">Le salarié a-t-il un projet professionnel ?</td>
          <td>
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="choixPP" id="choixPP" value="LE">à Limousin Expansion
            </label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="choixPP" id="choixPP" value="CRL">au Conseil Régional du Limousin
            </label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="choixPP" id="choixPP" value="EXT">a l'extérieur
            </label>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label class="radio-inline">
              <input type="radio" name="choixPP" id="choixPP" value="0" checked>pas de projet professionnel
            </label>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" id="divChoixPP" style="display:none;">
    <label for="divChoixPP" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Si oui, préciser le projet</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <textarea class="form-control" name="divChoixPP" id="divChoixPP" rows="6" cols="20"></textarea>
    </div>
    <!-- .col-sm-6 -->
  </div>
  <!-- .form-group -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your usages of `||` is wrong. Your `if` condition should be like following.

```
if(this.value == 'LE' || this.value=='CRL' || this.value=='EXT' && this.checked){
    //do your task here
}
```